# Is there any parallel function for mapply?

Tags: r

I am looking for a function that will take two vectors simultaneously and perform parallel computing. For an example, if we want to use "sapply" in parallel with multiple cores, we use "parSapply()". I searched on google but did not find anything similar to "parMapply()". Any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `parallel` comes with the `mcmapply` function that behaves like `mapply` but can use mulitple cores.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. Does $parallel$ work similarly to $snow$ package? Do you have any idea?